# Banach lattice with AP but without BAP?

Tags: banach-spaces

Is there an example of a Banach lattice with the approximation property
of Grothendieck, but without the MAP (metric approximation property)?

Comment: What does MAP refer to?

Comment: Vote to close. 3rd junk post by this member.

Comment: MAP = metric approximation property.

Comment: Definitely NOT a junk post.  Unlike Reinov's other question, this one is not a well known problem and the answer might be simple given known techniques.

While Reinov should become aware of proper MO protocol, he deserves respect. I do not know him personally, but along with many other experts I value highly his research on approximation properties.

Comment: Casting 2nd vote to reopen. While I don't know enough about Banach spaces to judge the question, I am happy to take Bill Johnson's word for it. Can I also suggest that deleting the banach-spaces tag seems to have been unwise, because it reduced the chances of the question being seen by (specialist) people who could judge it.

Comment: Short question, short answer:  use construction in 

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Approximation+Property+Does+Not+Imply+the+Bounded+Approximation+Property+Johnson+Proceedings
